# How to inspect the body of an outgoing HTTP request created with `http-client` (Haskell)

Tags: http, haskell

I am using Haskell to send a POST HTTP request via the [`http-client`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-client-0.4.2.2/docs/Network-HTTP-Client.html#t:Request) package, but as a response i am getting an error from the remote server. I would like to inspect my request in order to be sure that i am sending the expected parameters in the body.

I managed to bind my request to a variable in the Haskell interpreter, but i can't figure out how to see its body. When i use `requestBody` on my request i get a value of type [RequestBody](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-client-0.4.2.2/docs/Network-HTTP-Client.html#t:RequestBody), but it is not an instance of show.

In the library i can't find any helpful function. There are just many constructors, and some functions related to a `Popper` type.

How can i inspect that value? This seems a common use case to me, yet the library doesn't seem to support it. Am i using it wrong?

#### Edit:

I know what Wireshark is and how to use it, but i expect to be able to programmatically inspect what i am sending

Comment: I know this is not what you're asking for, but if you just want to debug your server, you could do worse than just sniffing the traffic and looking at it, with e.g. [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`RequestBody` has five constructors.

```
data RequestBody
    = RequestBodyLBS L.ByteString
    | RequestBodyBS S.ByteString
    | RequestBodyBuilder Int64 Builder
    | RequestBodyStream Int64 (GivesPopper ())
    | RequestBodyStreamChunked (GivesPopper ())
```

First two are wrappers of bytestring, the third is a `Blaze.ByteString.Builder` which can be easily converted to bytestring, the last two are functions of type `(IO ByteString -> IO a) -> IO a` as the type synonym showed:

```
type Popper = IO S.ByteString
type NeedsPopper a = Popper -> IO a
type GivesPopper a = NeedsPopper a -> IO a
```

feed them `>>= print` multiple  times and you will get the complete request body printed to console.

You should not do this because these `GivesPopper ()` generators can only be executed once: if you extract the content beforehand then the request body will not be sent to the server. That's why they didn't provide a Show instance for `RequestBody` data type. You'd better capture the buckets containing your http request with e.g. [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/).

---

> I have a data structure in my code and i don't see why i shouldn't be able to inspect it. You mention that inspecting the request might somehow consume it. This is weird in a language like Haskell where immutability and explicit side effects are the rule

That's right for most of the types in Haskell, but `Popper` is actually `IO S.ByteString`, a bytestring stream (usually) populated by a file handler, while handler in Haskell is an `MVar` which is not so different from variables in imperative languages: it may be a value or null, may be assigned and reassigned and the side effect is visible globally.

An example from `Network.HTTP.Client.MultipartFormData`:

```
streamFile :: FilePath -> GivesPopper ()
streamFile fp np =
    withFile fp ReadMode $ np . go
  where
    -- go :: Handle -> Popper 
    go h = BS.hGetSome h defaultChunkSize
```

Comment: Right, i can pattern match on the constructor and get the ByteString back! I didn't think about this at first!

Suggesting Wireshark is like a surrender. I have a data structure in my code and i don't see why i shouldn't be able to inspect it.

You mention that inspecting the request might somehow consume it. This is weird in a language like Haskell where immutability and explicit side effects are the rule

Comment: I involved the library author in the discussion https://github.com/snoyberg/http-client/issues/184

Comment: maybe i could use a [dummyConnection](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-client-0.4.2.2/docs/Network-HTTP-Client-Internal.html#v:dummyConnection) with a [requestBuilder](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-client-0.4.2.2/docs/Network-HTTP-Client-Internal.html#v:requestBuilder), but i am not sure how to use the `dummyConnection`

Comment: @danza I don't think `dummyConnection` will send the request to any remote server and `requestBuilder` will consume the request anyway. One solution may be to generate exactly the same request twice (if it's ever possible in your program) and print the `RequestBody` of one, send to server the other. You definitely won't be able to do `show :: RequestBody -> String` still.

Comment: I hoped to use `dummyConnection` in order to get a serialisation of my request without getting into the different constructors, i don't care about sending it to the server at the moment, and i have no problems with consuming it. In the end i managed to serialise it writing a partial function which extracted the strict bytestring. I found out that was the constructor in my case. Thanks a lot for your support, i was lost!